# Excel Vba Macro to Wrap, Center, Auto Size Columns and Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get this column to do a few things, but when it gets to wrap text and center it isn't doing it...it doesn't error but it doesn't wrap or center...any thoughts? ty in advance!

```
Sub Resize_Columns_And_Rows_No_Header()
'
'Resize_Columns_And_Rows Macro
'
'Declaration
  Dim wkSt As String
  Dim wkBk As Worksheet
  Dim temp As Variant
  Dim lastCol As Long

  wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name
' This Loops Through All Sheets
  For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      On Error Resume Next
      wkBk.Activate
      lastCol = wkBk.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'This is only needed if you are wrapping the text
      wkBk.Rows.WrapText = True
'This is to center align all rows
      wkBk.Rows.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
' Resize Columns
      wkBk.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
' Resize Rows
      wkBk.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
  Next wkBk
  Sheets(wkSt).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me.  Try removing the `On Error` statement and see whether you are getting an error.  (The only thing I can spot as a potential problem would be the `Columns.Count` (i.e. columns on the active sheet), which should be `wkBk.Columns.Count` (i.e. columns on the sheet you are processing), but with the `wkBk.Activate` that **should** work OK.)

Comment: Is it really necessary to wrap text (and center align, autofit, etc.) on **every cell in every worksheet**. You'll gain a ton of efficiency if you  just stick to rows / columns with actual data. You'll also benefit from `With ... End With` construct. Also are you sure it doesn't wrap and center? Or does it only *appear* not too?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I would have thought that most of the formatting options would be more efficient if they applied to everything, rather than just selected rows and/or columns, as it doesn't then need to store a custom format for the "unusual" rows/columns (but I have never delved very deep into the inner workings, so I am happy to be told that I am imagining things)

Comment: @YowE3K - I have heard that before as well. I have not delved deeper either, but I always shy away from it because i have seen serious bloating issues where files had formats or whatever in far away distant rows / columns.

Comment: Yep - Excel keeps track of all the formatting styles used in a workbook.  If all cells are the same, it counts as 1 format. After the code is applied, the workbook has a bunch more, but after saving and reloading, and Excel recalculates all formats used, you might at most have one more than pre-code because cells formatted prior to code now include the additional formatting options. In a way, Excel performs a SELECT DISTINCT on all formatting cell styles used when the workbook is open.  I've run into issues with too many cells formats - but that arose around 97' or 2k edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

The thing is though, **WrapText = True** and **Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit**, sort of contradict each other.

```
Sub Resize_Columns_And_Rows_No_Header2()

Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sheet
            With .Cells.Rows
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With '.Cells.Rows
            .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With 'sheet
    Next sheet

    currentSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

By the way, do you also need a:

```
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

?

Comment: Using both WrapText = True and Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit would be appropriate if there were lines of text separated by line feed characters within the cells.

Comment: Please, please, please, please change "sorta" to "sort of".  Please!

Comment: @YowE3K - you can edit yourself and it will go to user as a suggested edit to approve.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I shouldn't have listened to you :D - my edit gets made, not just suggested - now I will worry as to whether I am going to incur the wrath of someone who doesn't like my grammar usage.  (I'll +1 the question now that it has been edited though - maybe that will mollify them.)

Comment: @YowE3K - My bad. I could have sworn that the edit doesn't go through until user approves. I am pretty sure he can rollback though. It's been a while but I went through this with an answer I made at one point where the suggested edits did not make sense.

Comment: lulz - crazy peoplez :)